# How to place tcolorbox at bottom of page

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, tcolorbox, alignment

Does anyone know how set a tcolorbox textbox to appear at the bottom of a page, similar to how you can set figures to appear at the top or bottom of a page? I have looked everywhere but no answers to this specific question can be found online. I am looking for functionality equivalent to how figures will be automatically aligned with the bottom of the page they are referenced in:

```
\begin{figure}[!b]
... figure contents...
\end{figure}
```

Here is how I have my tcolorbox item set up:

```
\tcbset{ 
    noteStyle/.style={ 
        breakable, 
        enhanced, 
        outer arc=0pt, 
        arc=0pt, 
        colframe=noteTitleBlue, 
        colback=noteBackgroundBlue!20, 
        attach boxed title to top left, 
        boxed title style={ 
            colback=noteTitleBlue, 
            outer arc=0pt, 
            arc=0pt, top=0pt, 
            bottom=0pt 
        }, 
        fonttitle=\sffamily 
    } 
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{note}[2][]{
    noteStyle, 
    label=#2, 
    fontupper=\footnotesize, 
    title=Note~\thetcbcounter, 
    overlay unbroken and first={
        \path let \p1=(title.north east), 
        \p2=(frame.north east) in node[anchor=west, 
        font=\sffamily, 
        color=noteTitleBlue, 
        text width=\x2-\x1] at (title.east) {#1};
    }, 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you not simple insert it in `figure` environment?

Comment: That worked! I honestly didn't realize that that was an option. I think I better understand how 'environments' work in general as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `float` converts a `tcolorbox` into a `floating` object, and `floatplacement` fixes positioning preferences order

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[float, floatplacement=b]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]