# tcolorbox failing to float to bottom of page

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

I want to float a [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) to the bottom of a page of text, but it doesn't reliably work.  This question is very closely related to [How to place tcolorbox at bottom of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600230/how-to-place-tcolorbox-at-bottom-of-page), but not a complete duplicate as the solution there doesn't work in this particular case.  I suspect that's exposing a lack of understanding on my part as to how floats work.

Here's a MWE, which when I process with `xelatex`, produces a two-page PDF.  The main text is on the first page, and the `tcolorbox` is floating in the middle of the next.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[float,floatplacement=b]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `[float,floatplacement=b]` demonstrates that there is plenty of space at the bottom of the first page for it.  Interestingly, it works fine I change the contents to be as follows, despite this having far more content:

```
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[float,floatplacement=b]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

It looks like LaTeX has some in-built maximum size for a `[b]` float.  If so, can it be disabled, either globally or for a particular `tcolorbox`?

(I know that in this MWE, I can easily achieve what I want with a non-floating `tcolorbox`, with a `\vfill` beforehand to move it to the bottom of the page.  I can't readily do that in the real document.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`article` sets `\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}` so bottom floats can not be more than 30% of the page, you could increase that or the `!` float option says to ignore the constraints, so

[image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[float,floatplacement=!b]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I know the cause, I'm erring towards adding `\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.67}` to my preamble.  But a `!b` placement works too.